# Unable to install R JavaGD package on OSX

Tags: java, r

I have tried to install the `R` package `JavaGD`on MacOS 10.14.6. My `R` version is 3.6.1. When I do instal.packages there is apparently no error, but when I do in R console:

> library(JavaGD)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘JavaGD’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>    unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/JavaGD/libs/JavaGD.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/JavaGD/libs/JavaGD.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/JavaGD/libs/JavaGD.so
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: I am interested to hear what others suggest. My (basic, but possibly useful) advice would be to uninstall and reinstall java

Comment: Are you sure this location exists: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib`

Comment: It only exists now because I am installing `jdk 11`. Before I had `jdk1.8.0_144.jdk`

Comment: When running `sudo R CMD javareconf ...` I get ```clang-6.0: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/XCode/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from conftest.c:1:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h:39:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine in macOS 10.14.

[image]

However, make sure your `R` and `Java` environments are correctly configured.

It might be a little bit of struggle to properly configure `Java` in `R`.

I suggest to start with simple `Java` code:

http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/

to make sure you can actually use `Java` inside `R`.

In some cases it might be required to rebuild `rJava` package.

http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/

Anyway, I guess that first step is to make sure you can actually bind these two worlds.